# How to explode this array?

Tags: php, xml, arrays, explode

I have tried to explode the returned array and it just doesn't want to display. Obviously I am doing something wrong. Here is the code for the bit I am having trouble exploding.

index.php

```
include "class_client.php";
$client->set('place', 'home');
$client->placeLookup();
$client->screen($client->response()); //want to replace this to print the selected exploded data as shown at the bottom of this question
```

class_client.php

```
private $data = array();
private $response = NULL;

public function set($key, $value) {
$this->data[$key] = $value;
return $this;
}

private function get($key) {
return $this->data[$key];
}

public function response() {
return $this->response;
}

public function placeLookup() {
$this->response = $this->srv()->placeLookup(array('place' => $this->get('place')));
return $this;
}
```

Output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [return] => stdClass Object
        (
            [fields] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [entries] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [key] => place.status
                                    [value] => HERE
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [key] => place.name
                                    [value] => home
                                )

                        )

                )

            [operation] => place.lookup
            [success] => TRUE
        )

)
```

**The only data I want to see in output on index.php is;**

> HERE (which comes from [value] in [0] in the entries array)
>   home (which comes from [value] in [1] in the entries array)

Would also prefer if I can explode within class_client.php and return the values back as the new array to index.php (to minimise/hide the code within index.php).

Thank you!!

Comment: To clarify, you want `$client->response()` to return an array like `array('HERE', 'home')`?

Comment: @Kevin: Exactly right :) thanks for making that much clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on PHP 5.3+, you can replace your `response` method with this:

```
public function response() {
    return array_map(function($a) {
        return $a->value;
    }, $this->response->return->fields->entries);
}
```

Otherwise, try:

```
public function response() {
    return array_map(array($this, 'getValue'), $this->response->return->fields->entries);
}

public function getValue($obj) {
    return $obj->value;
}
```

**EDIT:** Your new index.php:

```
include "class_client.php";
$client->set('place', 'home');
$client->placeLookup();
list($status, $name) = $client->response();
$client->screen('Status: '.$status.', Name: '.$name);
```

Comment: @Kevin: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Comment: I'll give you an alternative, but out of curiosity, which PHP version are you on?

Comment: @Kevin: Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array

Comment: @Kevin: Perfect! Thank you. Is there a way to strip the output of: Array ( [0] => [1] => ) to just leave the entry value data?

Comment: You can concatenate the array values with a delimiter using something like: `implode("\n", $array);`

Comment: @Kevin: One more question, sorry. How can I assign a variable to each of those outputs [0] and [1] so I can later do a little if statement on either. The issue I have is I don't know what variable is assigned for the array. Do I just go for eg: $output1 = $this[0]; ?

Comment: @Kevin: Ok so I can implode using that in the response function, correct?

Comment: I guess it depends on what values can be in the `entries` array. If it's consistently `place.status` and `place.name` in that order, you can do `list($status, $name) = $array;`

Comment: re: implode, yes. Just wrap the entire return value in an implode: `return implode("\n", array_map(...));`

Comment: @Kevin: Yup it will be consistent as those names in that order. Are you able to update the code with showing the assigned vars to the data? sorry to be a pain..

Comment: @Kevin: tried the following in index.php.. list($status, $name) = $array; echo $status; and does not show?

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks! But just outputs "Status: A, Name: V" ?

Comment: Looks to be a string, so I have done as follows; $out = explode("\n", $client->response()); $client->screen('Status: '.$out[0].'<br>Name: '.$out[1]); - is this the best way? (it is displaying properly now)

Comment: You ought to brush up on your PHP basics. Try reading a few tutorials.